# How do I generate number pattern in triangular form

Tags: c

I want to print this pattern like right angled triangle

```
0   
909   
89098   
7890987    
678909876   
56789098765   
4567890987654   
345678909876543   
23456789098765432   
1234567890987654321
```

I wrote the following code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>

    void main()
    {
        clrscr();
        int i,j,x,z,k,f=1;

        for ( i=10;i>=1;i--,f++)
        {
            for(j=1;j<=f;j++,k--)
            {
                k=i;

                if(k!=10)
                {
                    printf("%d",k);
                }

                if(k==10)
                {
                    printf("0");
                }

            }

            for(x=1;x<f;x++,z--)
            {
                z=9;
                printf("%d",z);
            }

            printf("%d/n");
        }

        getch();
    }
```

What is wrong with this code? When I check manually it seems correct but when compiled gives different pattern

Comment: What output are you getting? (is it a long sequence of `9` by any chance?)

Comment: @Hasturkun 0864/n999864/n88899864 and goes on ...(i just wrote few lines of output)

Comment: The first issue is `printf("%d/n");` - this needs to be  `printf("\n");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fairly simple: use two loops, one for counting up and one for counting down. Print literal `"0"` between the two.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 10 - i; j < 10; j++)
            printf("%d", j);

        printf("0");

        for (int j = 9; j >= 10 - i; j--)
            printf("%d", j);

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @meaning-matters [Your argument is invalid.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle) - also, have you read the "like this" part of the question? (You are probably confusing right trinagles with [equilateral triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle). Yup, maths is hard, English is even harder...)

Comment: @VigneshVicky No, it doesn't, it generates the exact output you want. [Link](http://ideone.com/wRe42F)

Comment: @meaning-matters A 'right angled triangle' is a triangle with a 90* corner and as far as I can see the code from carbonic acid seems to do that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Carbonic Acid, your answer is correct as far as the question allows. Vote up.

Answer (score 2):

Like H2CO3's, but since we're only printing single digits why not use `putchar()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  int i, j;

  for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
    // Left half.
    for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)
      putchar('9' - i + j + 1);
    // Center zero.
    putchar('0');
    // Right half.
    for(j = 0; j < i; ++j)
      putchar('9' - i + j + 1);
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Because I was not using a large enough part of my brain :) +1.

Answer (score 0):

Modified Code: 
Check your errors:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<conio.h>

int main()
{
// clrscr();
 int i,j,x,z,k,f=1;

 for ( i=10;i>=1;i--,f++)
 {
     k=i;                    // K=i should be outside of loop.
     for(j=1;j<=f;j++,k++)
     {

         if(k!=10)
         {
             printf("%d",k);
         }

         if(k==10)
         {
        printf("0");
         }
}
     z=9;                    //z=9 should be outside loop.
     for(x=1;x<f;x++,z--)
     {
         printf("%d",z);
     }

printf("\n");

}
//getch();
return 0;
}
```

You are defining k=i inside the for loop(loop which has j) so every time k gets value of i and thus it always get value of i and prints that value and your another condition(if(k==10)) will never be true because every time k takes value of i and i is less than 10 after first iteration of loop and z=9 inside loop so every time loop is executed it is taking value z=9 so it is printing wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C# version:

```
static void DrawNumberTriangle()
{
    for (int line = 10; line >=1; line--)
    {
        for (int number = line; number < 10; number++)
        {
            System.Console.Write(number);
        }
        System.Console.Write("0");
        for (int number = 9; number > line - 1; number--)
        {
            System.Console.Write(number);
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

I'd suggest renaming your i,j,x,z,k,f variables to ones that have meaning like the one's I used. This helps making your code easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than output the mid 0 using printf, why not print it using the loops itself.
The following short and simple code can be used:

```
int main()
{
    int m = 10, n, p;
    while(m >= 1)
    {
        for(n = m; n <= 10; n++)
            printf("%d", n % 10);
        for(p = n - 2; p >= m; p--)
            printf("%d", p );
        printf("\n");
        m--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For high throughput (though of questionable merit in terms of clarity):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char const digits[] = "1234567890";
    char const rdigits[] = "9876543210";

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
        int k = i % 10;
        fputs(digits + 9 - k, stdout);
        for (int j = 9; j < i; j += 10) fputs(digits, stdout);
        for (int j = 9; j < i; j += 10) fputs(rdigits, stdout);
        fwrite(rdigits, 1, k, stdout);
        fputs("\n", stdout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int i){
    if(i == 10){
        putchar('0');
        return ;
    } else {
        printf("%d", i);
        print(i+1);
        printf("%d", i);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int i;
    for(i = 10; i>0; --i){
        print(i);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```